# Insert condition in xpath java

Tags: java, eclipse, appium-android, testng-eclipse

I have this screen in an android application.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jzakh.jpg)

I'm trying to run a method in order to check the number displayed in the car's image and find the first one different from zero then click on the picture that contain this number .

I tried this code:

public void test5_MAP_Assets_Position(String XX) {

```
        try {
            Assert.assertTrue( Integer.parseInt(XX)>Integer.parseInt("0"));
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@text='"+XX+"']")) ;
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='view_asset_item_image_view' and (./preceding-sibling::* | ./following-sibling::*) ] and //*[@text>='"+XX+"']")).click();                 
            } 
        catch (AssertionError e) {          
            }   
    }
```

}

I got this error :

```
[RemoteTestNG] detected TestNG version 6.14.2
Jan 30, 2019 9:52:27 AM io.appium.java_client.remote.AppiumCommandExecutor$1 
 lambda$0
 INFO: Detected dialect: OSS
 [Utils] [ERROR] [Error] org.testng.TestNGException: 
 Cannot inject @Test annotated Method [test5_MAP_Assets_Position] with 
 [class java.lang.String].
 For more information on native dependency injection please refer to 
 http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#native-dependency-injection
 at org.testng.internal.Parameters.checkParameterTypes(Parameters.java:407)

 FAILED: test5_MAP_Assets_Position org.testng.TestNGException: 
 Cannot inject @Test annotated Method [test5_MAP_Assets_Position] with [class java.lang.String].
 For more information on native dependency injection please refer to 
 http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#native-dependency-injection
```

Please help me to fix this problem.

Answer (score 0):

`XX` should be a local variable and not method parameter:

```
public void test5_MAP_Assets_Position() {
    String XX = "1234";
    try {
        Assert.assertTrue( Integer.parseInt(XX)>Integer.parseInt("0"));
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@text='"+XX+"']")) ;
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='view_asset_item_image_view' and (./preceding-sibling::* | ./following-sibling::*) ] and //*[@text>='"+XX+"']")).click();
```

Or use [Parameters with DataProviders](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#parameters-dataproviders)

> you can use a Data Provider to supply the values you need to test.  A Data Provider is a method on your class that returns an array of array of objects.